# Set<> inside of Map<>, print everything?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to read a `.txt` file, take all the words inside of that text and somehow print out how many times each words is in the text.

For example, take this text:

```
"A bright day a man walked into a bar and asked for a beer. He was denied the beer because he was a sheep"
```

Should give this:

```
5: a
2: he, beer
1: bright, day, walked, into, bar, asked, denied, was, the,because, man, and, for
```

Here is my code:

```
private void computeFrequencyMap() throws IOException {
    TreeMap<String, Integer> dMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filen));
    String line;
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
         String [] words = line.split("\\s+");
      for (String word : words) {
          word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        if (!dMap.containsKey(word.toLowerCase())) {
          dMap.put(word.toLowerCase(), 1);
        } else {
          int count = dMap.get(word.toLowerCase());
          dMap.put(word.toLowerCase(), count + 1);
        }
      }
    }
    TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> sMap = new TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dMap.entrySet()) {
        if(sMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())){
            //sMap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }else{
            sMap.put(entry.getValue(), new HashSet<String>());
        }
   }
   for (Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> entry : sMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

This is what I get when I run the code:

```
1 []
2 []
3 []
4 []
5 []
6 []
7 []
8 []
9 []
10 []
11 []
12 []
14 []
16 []
18 []
27 []
32 []
33 []
38 []
44 []
54 []
71 []
```

I've only come so far, cant get the "add to the set" part right, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually add the words to the when you reverse the map:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> sMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dMap.entrySet()) {
    Integer appearances = entry.getValue();
    Set<String> words = sMap.get(appearances);
    if (words == null) {
        words = new HashSet<>();
        sMap.put(appearances, words);
    }
    words.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile. To make it work,

Set<String> words = sMap.get(appearances); should be replaced with HashSet<String> words = sMap.get(appearances);

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JavaHopper I had to tweak the code with your answe, works great! Thanks

Comment: @JavaHopper true - or better yet, define `sMap` properly - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue

```
private void computeFrequencyMap() throws IOException {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> dMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String word : words) {
                word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
                if (!dMap.containsKey(word.toLowerCase())) {
                    dMap.put(word.toLowerCase(), 1);
                } else {
                    int count = dMap.get(word.toLowerCase());
                    dMap.put(word.toLowerCase(), count + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dMap);
        TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> sMap = new TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dMap.entrySet()) {
            if (sMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
                 ((Set<String>)sMap.get(entry.getValue())).add(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                HashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
                set.add(entry.getKey());
                sMap.put(entry.getValue(), set);
            }
        }
        for (Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> entry : sMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to tweak it a little Muireniks answer with your answer, and it works perfectly!

Comment: no problem. Use LinkedHashSet instead, if you want order to be preserved

Comment: Thank you again, will look into that!

Comment: Did "thumbs-up" to the other guys answer first, before you wrote your answe, sorry cant thumbs-up twice :(

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Java answer. But your question is a perfect example for how to use classic Unix shell tools ([`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr), [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq)):

- `tr` converts all upper case to lower case letters
- `sed` removes the dot `.`
- `sort` sorts the word alphabetically
- `uniq` counts them
- `sort` sorts the counts

Try this:

```
$ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < so.txt |\
  sed 's/\.//' |\
  tr " " "\n" |\
  sort |\
  uniq -c |\
  sort -r -n
```

Output:

```
      5 a
      2 was
      2 he
      2 beer
      1 walked
      1 the
      1 sheep
      1 man
      1 into
      1 for
      1 denied
      1 day
      1 bright
      1 because
      1 bar
      1 asked
      1 and
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is how it could be done in Java 8:

```
String content = "A bright day a man walked into a bar and asked for a beer. He was denied the beer because he was a sheep";
Map<Long, List<String>> mapByCount = Arrays.stream(content.split("( |\\.)+"))
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            () -> new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()),
            mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())
        )
    );

System.out.println(mapByCount);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    5=[a],
    2=[was, he, beer], 
    1=[for, bright, the, into, bar, walked, asked, and, because, man, denied, day, sheep] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just started learning about lambda expression in school, should look more into it, very cool!

Comment: @CarltonJr. Good News! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    private static final String REGEX = "( |\\.)+";

    public static Map<String, Integer> getWordCount(String txt) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String str : txt.split(REGEX)) {
            str = str.toLowerCase();

            if (!map.containsKey(str)) {
                map.put(str, 1);
                continue;
            }

            int count = map.get(str);
            map.put(str, count + 1);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static Map<Integer, String> reverseMap(Map<String, Integer> wordCount) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        Set<String> keys = wordCount.keySet();

        for (String key : keys) {
            int val = wordCount.get(key);
            if (!map.containsKey(val)) {
                map.put(val, key);
                continue;
            } else {
                String data = map.get(val) + "," + key;
                map.put(val, data);
            }
        }

        return map;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths
                .get("input.txt")));

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = getWordCount(content);
        Map<Integer, String> result = reverseMap(wordCount);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```